# Does concatenate layers and merge layers in keras same thing ? Does concatenate means averaging the output of two layers?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp, lstm

I am making a language LSTM model in keras. Does concatening two layers help and is it same as merging layers. What exactly concatenation does ? Does it mean we average the output of two layers when we concatenate them or we stack them on top of each other ?

Comment: Just a clarification, you do not merge/concatenate layers, you merge/concatenate the outputs of the layers. This is important because layers can have multiple inputs and outputs.

Comment: Merging does averaging and concatenation does concatenate (with outputs in mid as @MatiasValdenegro said)

Comment: @RussellB No, merge is a general concept, it could be concatenate, average, min, max, etc.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Keras Documentation: https://keras.io/layers/merge/

> Concatenate
>   It takes as input a list of tensors, all of the same shape except for
>   the concatenation axis, and returns a single tensor, the concatenation
>   of all inputs.

It's similiar to Concatenate in other implemenetations. And the confusion is similiar to mistaking 2 Concatenate 2 = 22 while 2 added 2 = 4.

A Concatenate will change the shape of the layer, along a given axis, the argument given.

As a tangent, I think Concatenate is easier to work with in Functional than Sequential models.